# LINQ. Как отсортировать по нескольким параметрам?

Tags: c#, linq

К списку предъявляется требование - **сортировка может происходить сразу по нескольким полям**. Порядок сортировочных полей заранее известен, а необходимость выполнить сортировку по конкретным полям - нет. Условно, сейчас нужна сортировка по одному полю, через некоторое время по другому полю, ещё через время по всем полям.

В приведённом ниже примере можно заметить, что если необходимо, чтобы сортировка производилась сразу по двум полям, то факт первой сортировки затрётся второй. Хотелось бы решить проблему конструкцией последовательных друг за другом `ThenBy`, но никак не могу додуматься до изящного решения. Наведите на мысль или приведите пример решения проблемы для данного кода.

```
var dataList = new List<Data>
{
    new Data(1, DateTime.Now.Date),
    new Data(0, DateTime.Now.Date),
    new Data(2, DateTime.Now.Date),
    new Data(3, DateTime.Now.Date),
    new Data(4, DateTime.Now.Date),
    new Data(5, DateTime.Now.Date),
    new Data(6, DateTime.Now.Date),
    new Data(7, DateTime.Now.Date),
    new Data(8, DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)),
    new Data(9, DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1))
};

bool condition1 = new Random().NextBoolean();
bool condition2 = new Random().NextBoolean();

if (condition1)
    dataList = dataList.OrderBy(x => x.id).ToList();

if (condition2)
    dataList = dataList.OrderByDescending(x => x.date).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Пришел к подобному решению:

```
var query = dataList.AsQueryable() as IOrderedQueryable<Data>;

SortOrder sortOrder = (SortOrder)new Random().Next(4);
switch(sortOrder)
{
    case SortOrder.IdAscending: query = query.OrderBy(x => x.id);   break;
    case SortOrder.IdDescending: query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.id); break;
    case SortOrder.DateAscending: query = query.OrderBy(x => x.date); break;
    case SortOrder.DateDescending: query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.date); break;
    default: query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.date); break;
}

query = query.ThenBy(x => x.id);
```

Ввел промежуточную переменную IOrderedQuarable. Нагрузил её сортировкой в зависимости от условий. И после этого дополнительно задаю второстепенную сортировку.

Answer (score 0):

Я слегка модифицировал ваш пример, применив паттерн-матчинг.
Преобразование в Queryable не нужно.

```
var query = sortOrder switch
{
    SortOrder.IdAscending => dataList.OrderBy(x => x.id),
    SortOrder.IdDescending => dataList.OrderByDescending(x => x.id),
    SortOrder.DateAscending => dataList.OrderBy(x => x.date),
    SortOrder.DateDescending => dataList.OrderByDescending(x => x.date),
    _ => dataList.OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
};

query = query.ThenBy(x => x.id);
```

Comment: `SortOrder.DateDescending =>` можно убрать, дубликат с "по умолчанию".